# Filter a list of objects in Android using gradle-retrolambda and Lightweight-Stream-API

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8

I am trying to filter a List of Objects in Java in my Android App, for this I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13140130/3546389) (Java 8 suggestion) , but as Lambdas aren't supported in Android SDK, I used [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) but I get this runtime-error
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)`

This is the line of code I am using:

```
List<CaseDetails> closedCaseDetailsList = caseDetailsList.stream().filter(item -> item.caseClosed.equals(true)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I believe it should work as **gradle-retrolambda** should be taking care of the Lambdas on Java7.

Next, I tried [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API) along with **gradle-retrolambda** and changed my code a little, according to the usage of Lightweight-Stream-API

```
List<CaseDetails> closedCaseDetailsList = Stream.of(caseDetailsList).filter(item -> item.caseClosed.equals(true)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it gives me an error over `Collectors.toList()` saying

```
collect
(com.annimon.stream.Collector<? super com.example.yankee.cw.CaseDetails,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)
in Stream cannot be applied
to
 (java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.List<T>>)
```

I also tried explicitly type-casting the `Stream` to `List<CaseDetails>` but that didn't work (of course).

I tried Slack communities, SO Chat-rooms but couldn't find a solution. The closest thing I found to my problem was this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788152/android-nosuchmethoderror-with-static-method-in-interface-using-retrolambda) but it is a different error.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can only give you an example for [streamsupport](https://github.com/stefan-zobel/streamsupport)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import java8.util.stream.Collectors;
import java8.util.stream.StreamSupport;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;

public class CaseDetails {

    Boolean caseClosed = FALSE;

    public CaseDetails(Boolean caseClosed) {
        this.caseClosed = caseClosed;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "caseClosed: " + caseClosed;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<CaseDetails> caseDetailsList = Arrays.asList(
                new CaseDetails(TRUE), new CaseDetails(FALSE), new CaseDetails(
                        TRUE));
        List<CaseDetails> closedCaseDetailsList = StreamSupport
                .stream(caseDetailsList)
                .filter(item -> item.caseClosed.equals(TRUE))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(closedCaseDetailsList);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it. My `Collectors` was a Java7 class that was imported earlier and it was continuing to use the same. Thanks a lot to you and @Jahnold

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately Retrolambda doesn't backport streams.  From the docs:

> Retrolambda lets you run Java 8 code with **lambda expressions, method references and try-with-resources statements** on Java 7, 6 or 5

For a backport of the lightweight streams api you could try:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/

Alternatively you could achieve something similar using RxJava

Comment: Thanks, I also tried using Apache Commons with Predicates but faced some errors in that too. I'll give this a try, thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, isn't the Lightweight-Stream-API able to make up for this shortcoming on the part of retrolambda ? How can I get around the second error that I have mentioned ?

Comment: I've not tried Lightweight-Steam-API only the streamsupport library.  It did work but I often found issues like you have above due to the changed interface names - I image this will be where the problem is.  I just use Rx now

Comment: I tried using StreamSupport, following [this] (https://github.com/streamsupport/streamsupport#usage) , but now when I write 
`List<CaseDetails> closedCaseDetailsList = RefStreams.of(caseDetailsList).filter(item -> item.caseClosed.equals(true)).collect(Collectors.toList());` It shows that `caseClosed` can't be resolved. `caseClosed` is a boolean member of `CaseDetails`. 
Also, I added RxJava to my project and tried my first approach (in the question) but I still get the same error as before. 
I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks again.

Comment: @Yankee It's not `RefStreams.of` (that's the equivalent to Java 8 `Stream.of` and produces a stream that contains your List as the single element). Instead use the static method `java8.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(Collection)` and all should be fine.

Comment: @Sartorius Thank you for the response. I tried this and it gives the same error (squiggly red line around `Collectors.toList()`) as I've mentioned in the question ( the 2nd error). Don't know what's causing it.

Comment: @Sartorius this is the statement `List<CaseDetails> closedCaseDetailsList = java8.util.stream.StreamSupport.stream(caseDetailsList).filter(item -> item.caseClosed.equals(true)).collect(Collectors.toList());` and I have added all the dependencies for `streamsupport`.  


There's something I want to know though, we're using `java8.util.stream.StreamSupport` here, so where is the `streamsupport` library (for which I've added the dependecies) being used ?

Comment: @Yankee Error message? I'll post an example as answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @Sartorius 
There's no runtime error , only the compiler gives an error ,  its same as the second error in question, just that instead of `com.annimon.stream` now it's `com.util.stream`  

Error:
`collect
(com.util.stream.Collector<? super com.example.yankee.cw.CaseDetails,java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>)
in Stream cannot be applied
to
 (java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.List<T>>) `

Comment: @Sartorius Yes, please and thank you for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Yankee That doesn't make sense. What is `com.util.stream`? Why do you have a `collect` method that expects a `java.util.stream.Collector` instead of a `java8.util.stream.Collector`. Wrong imports? See my example for code that compiles.